# Текст в колонку и по центру

Tags: массивы, php, html

Вопрос такой делаю страницу log.php в нее должны приходить логи ну проблема такая информация приходит сплошным текстом а не в (столбик,колонку) и распологается не по центру помогите дописать буду очень признателен вот код страницы...

```
<center>
<b><font color="Green">Лог Действий</font></b><br>
<hr>
<input type="button" value="Обновить" onClick="window.location.reload( true );">
</center>
```

Comment: 1) Пользуйтесь таблицами (лучше попробуйте сами пару таблиц сверстать, ручками), 2) Не пользуйтесь старьем (напр. тегами `center`,`font` и т.п.)

Comment: 3)НЕ пользуйтесь таблицами ,если это не табличные данные и еще нескольких критичиских случаях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаем на странице блок и задаем ему стили.

```
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
<p><b>Лог Действий</b></p>
<input type="button" value="Обновить" onClick="window.location.reload( true );">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper{margin:0 auto;width:780px;}
p{color:green}
```